# How do I Stop Scrolling in a Specific Direction on a Specific Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have this code in JavaScript (+ jQuery, JS Library):

```js
var $curr = $(".scroll");
$('body').on('wheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
        $curr = $curr.nextUntil('#home');
        window.location.hash = $($curr).attr('id');
    }
    else {
        $curr = $curr.prevUntil('#discord');
        window.location.hash = $($curr).attr('id');
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Poppins;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
}

#home {
    background: red;
}

#pricing {
    background: green;
}

#discord {
    background: yellow;
}

.scroll {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home" class="scroll">Home</section>
<section id="pricing">Pricing</section>
<section id="discord">Discord</section>
```

(not sure why it skips pricing upon scrolling up, but it doesn't skip pricing on the real website)

Currently, When scrolling down, it will go to the sibling section below it and when scrolling up, it will go to the sibling section above it, but, when you're viewing `#discord`, if you scroll down you will be redirected to https://yoursite.com/website.html#undefined and then you will no longer be able to scroll up or down (the same happens when you scroll up when viewing #home).

How do I fix this?

Comment: You example code doesn't reproduce the issue you're describing. Will you be able to make it work as you see it, or perchance add more details so we can understand from your explanation.

Comment: This line `$($curr).attr('id');` when I print it using the console.log, it gives `undefined` even do, I can see that `$curr` provides an object with all shorts of methods and properties. I think the `attr('id')` may not be valid. What are you trying to obtain with `$($curr).attr('id');`.

Comment: Also, I don't see any tag (div, etc) that is using the class `.scroll`; therefore, this line `var $curr = $(".scroll");` is not going to find anything.

Comment: @acarlstein the section id home has the scroll class

Comment: @Adriano | I fixed the code (not sure why upon scrolling up it skips pricing but it doesn't do that on the actual website so ignore it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. You may have to modify it a little to your need.

```js
function jumpTo(id){
if (typeof id !== 'undefined'){   
    $("div.log").append("<br>jump to: " + id);
      var top = $("#" + id).position().top;
      $('html').scrollTop(top);
      //window.location.hash = id;      
    }  
}


// Below is one way to tackle the issue of getting 'undefined' when next() and prev() cannot find the following element.
// Think of a double-linkedlist and these are the method to navigate it; however, they don't stop at the ends when they don't find a next element and the thing crashes returning 'undefined'

// We keep a reference to the original code
$.fn.oldNext = $.fn.next;
$.fn.oldPrev = $.fn.prev;

// We override next().
// If there are elements, we return them else we return reference to discord section
$.fn.next = function(selector){
    var selector = selector || '';
    return this.oldNext(selector).length ? this.oldNext(selector) : $("#discord");
}

// We override prev().
// If there are elements, we return them else we return reference to home section
$.fn.prev = function(selector){
    var selector = selector || '';
    return this.oldPrev(selector).length ? this.oldPrev(selector) : $("#home");
}

// Wait for all the DOMs in the page to be loaded prior to execute this code
$(function() {

  // Lets obtain the selector object of the home section and jump to it.
  var $curr = $("#home");
  jumpTo("home");

  // Self Explanatory
  $('body').on('wheel', function(event) {  
  
      // I am implementing my own logger here
      $("div.log").append("<br> " + $curr.prev('section').attr('id'));
      
      // deltaY return a positive or negative value depending of the direction the wheel its turned.
      if (event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {             
      
         // jQuery next() method, without modifying it, returns undefined when can't find a next element. Good policy to check prior using.
         if (typeof $curr.next('section') !== 'undefined'){
           $curr = $curr.next('section');
         }else{
           $curr = $("#home");
         }
      } else {  
      
      // jQuery prev() method, without modifying it, returns undefined when can't find a previous element. Good policy to check prior using.
         if (typeof $curr.prev('section') !== 'undefined'){
           $curr = $curr.prev('section');            
         }else{
           $curr = $("#discord");
         }
      }

      var id = $curr.attr('id');
      jumpTo(id);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;  
}

div.log {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh  
  border: 1px black solid;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home" class="scroller">Home</section>
<section id="pricing" class="scroller">Pricing</section>
<section id="discord" class="scroller">Discord</section>
<div class="log">Log goes here</div>
```

Comment: not sure what code on a plate does to teach anyone anything but each to their own I guess

Comment: This works, thanks! I'd just like to change one thing, when you scroll up in #home? how can I make it so that it doesn't scroll up to #discord? and when you scroll down in #discord, how do I make it stop scrolling down to #home?

Comment: @Tigerrrrr, I modified the code so they stop at `#home` when scrolling up and stop at `#discord` when scrolling down.

Comment: @PoopyDoop, I added comments to the code so you can learn from it.

Comment: Let me know if you folks have more questions.

Comment: @acarlstein | Perfect! (BTW some people don't need a full explanation because we can tell by the code itself).

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
if(typeof $($curr).attr('id') !== "undefined")
{
  window.location.hash = $($curr).attr('id');
}
```

which would stop it failing

Comment: I tried this before, it works when you're scrolling down but once you reach the end it stops you from going to both next or previous sections (it should only stop you from going to the next section), (same happens when scrolling up, should only stop you from going to the prev section)